# Is there a way to blend data from multiple sources with Google's new BigQuery?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a few data tables that I've loaded into the Google Cloud Console to use with BigQuery.  Originally I was working by learning to manually write queries (new to the platform but have some basic knowledge with SQL query structure) but with the release of Connected Sheets some additional people that I work with would be able to also create better reporting with data sets without knowing SQL.  However, when loading up Connected Sheets, it seems to only allow selecting 1 data table and not connecting with any others.  Is there a way with Connected Sheets to load and connect multiple data sources to create more complex reporting or is that functionality limited to written SQL queries only?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view that does the join of your multiple sources, and do Connected Sheets to that view